# Ruby Inheritance and overwriting class method

Tags: ruby, inheritance, class-method

I have set up two classes as shown below

```
class Parent

  def self.inherited(child)
    child.custom_class_method
  end

  def self.custom_class_method
    raise "You haven't implemented me yet!"
  end
end

class Child < Parent

  def self.custom_class_method
    "hello world"
  end
end
```

It seems that when the inheritence `Child < Parent` is evaluated, it calls `self.inherited`, which in turn raises the `Parent`'s version of `self.custom_class_method` instead of the `Child`'s. This is a problem because instead of getting an expected `"hello world"` I get an error raised saying `"You haven't implemented me yet!"`

Does `Child`'s `self.custom_class_method` not get evaluated until after `Parent`'s `self.inherited` is finished evaluating? And if so is there perhaps a work around this? Should I just not put a `raise` check on the Parent class?

Comment: This seems weird. The only way to get the Parent's `custom_class_method` should be to call on `super`. Otherwise, just called `Child.custom_class_method` should result in your "hello world" output. Could you please provide deeper logging?

Comment: Hmmm I agree it should ! But it seems as though I can replicate this by simply copy-pasting the code block into an `irb` console. It errors out when evaluating the `Child` class because of this very reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should clarify:

```
class Parent
  def self.inherited(child)
    puts "Inherited"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  puts "Starting to define methods"
  def self.stuff; end
end
```

Output makes it clear that `.inherited` gets called the moment you open the new class, not when you close it. Thus, as you guessed, `Child.custom_class_method` does not exist at the point when you are trying to call it - all `.inherited` sees is a blank slate.

(As to how to get around it... I can't say without more insight into what you are trying to do, unfortunately.)

Comment: Ah smart, I didn't think about debugging it like this! So what would be the best way to have abstract methods defined here? Do I just avoid raising errors (which is something I'm uncomfortable with to be honest).

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a Parent class that is able to execute code in the `self.inherited` block that will differ slightly from child class to child class. However to ensure we don't get errors, I want to make it mandatory that each child inheriting will define `custom_method` (hence why I made the Parent class raise).

Comment: Don't ask "how do I get child code executed at inherit", because you can't. It seems to be an XY problem. *Why* do you want to have child code executed at inherit? `.inherited` is there to notify parents of new children, not to run code on children. *Children* can run code on children (see my `puts`).

Comment: Ah I see. It seems as though my thought process intrinsically doesn't follow design principles of inheritance (which I suppose is fine). What I was hoping to do was to abstract logic that various classes were doing (they were each establishing a connection to their own customized database oat the class level) into a Parent class. Once inherited, the Parent would ask the child what database they wanted to connect to and do it for them. This would have hopefully abstracted and kept this logic DRY instead of having it repeated throughout each model.

Comment: Not sure I understand, so let me confirm: children are data models that need to connect to different databases, and expect the abstract parent model to handle the connection? That is not DRY, that is confusion of responsibilities. An abstract model should still be a model; which should not know about connecting to databases (especially not multiple databases). I'd make `DatabaseManager` (or something like that) handle the database connections, and have models ask it for appropriate connections, a single line in each model. (Again, super-vague, as I'm not in on the details of your design.)

Comment: Yes sorry for the vagueness but your advice is spot on actually. Thank you ! So in each child I'll call `DatabaseManager.connect_to(custom_database)` . Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe for implementing something similar to `final` in Java: How to write code when you close the class?

Answer (score 3):

The template pattern/lazy initialization may help solve your problem. The code assumes what is different between the children classes is the database connection information, perhaps just a table name or perhaps completely different databases. The parent class has all the code for creating and maintaining the connection, leaving the children only the responsibility of providing what is different.

```
class Parent
  def connection
    @connection ||= make_connection
  end

  def make_connection
    puts "code for making connection to database #{database_connection_info}"
    return :the_connection
  end

  def database_connection_info
    raise "subclass responsibility"
  end
end

class Child1 < Parent
  def database_connection_info
    {host: '1'}
  end
end

class Child2 < Parent
  def database_connection_info
    {host: '2'}
  end
end

child1 = Child1.new
child1.connection  # => makes the connection with host: 1
child1.connection  # => uses existing connection

Child2.new.connection  # => makes connection with host: 2
```

Comment: Awesome stuff, thanks! As a design question do you think this is any better/worse than abstracting this into a `DatabaseManager` model which maintains this connection logic and call `DatabaseManager.make_connection` in each class rather than inheriting it ?

Comment: Excellent question. Delegation vs inheritance is an age old question. Rails does persistence via inheritance (technically can include modules instead but typically done via inheritance). Many don't think persistence should be a responsibility of the class and go another direction, such as the data mapper pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern). Even if you fall in the persistence-is-a-responsibility camp, you may still want to abstract database behavior outside the class -- maybe a connection pool. There are good libraries for this, such as the sequel gem.

Comment: I am not married to the `DatabaseManager` idea, so this is another excellent suggestion. As I said, my answer was necessarily vague, as you know about your project way more than I do. The main point I was trying to make is that you can't do this on `inherit`. You can do it with an external manager, or with inherited method as here, or even with an `initialize` on an ancestor; but `inherited` has another purpose.

Comment: How to make the opposite, so so that method, instead of raising the error "children responsibility" would be impossible for them to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap `self.inherited` in `Thread.new`

Example:

```rb
class Foo
  def self.inherited klass
    begin
      puts klass::BAZ
    rescue => error
      # Can't find and autoload module/class "BAZ".
      puts error.message
    end

    Thread.new do
      # 123
      puts klass::BAZ
    end
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  BAZ = 123
end
```